# How to allow another account C to access IAM role given to account B by account A?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Account A `1234567890` has granted account B `0987654321` access to an a bunch of AWS services through a certain role:

```
arn:aws:iam:1234567890:role/bunch_of_access
```

And there's another account C that is owned by the same owner as B that needs the same role access but can't get it through account A.

- **Is there a way for account B to allow account C to also use the `arn:aws:iam:1234567890:role/bunch_of_access` role?**
- **Or is there a way to create a new role that let account C access root role from account B to get the access to `arn:aws:iam:1234567890:role/bunch_of_access` ?**

Comment: Can you create a group role and put accounts B and C in the group?

Comment: No, not from account A. The context is, B has access to C and vice versa. A gave access to B, C needs to access the same role as B.

Comment: I have not tested this but did you test with an IAM principal in account C assuming an intermediate role in account B where that intermediate role itself was allowed to assume the final role in account A? So, two calls to AssumeRole (from C to B, and then from B to A).

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, please accept it

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to do the role chaining... Putting policies everywhere and it looks like a mess for me. Undoing it and redoing it, and see how it goes.

Comment: @alvas did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with role chaining.

An entity in account C can assume a role in account B, and then using the assumed role it can assume the required role.

More on role chaining: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html